# Configure https on micronaut server by code

Tags: micronaut

I want to configure my server at startup using environment variables but all the documentation like [this](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#https) is about defining data at application.yml like this

```
ssl:
    port: 8443
    enabled: true
    keyStore:
      path: classpath:server.p12
      password: mypassword
      type: PKCS12
```

but this resource with a password is not secure to version in github.

**Is there a way to configure this by code for example using SslContextBuilder from netty in some way?**

Update 1:

A solution for this is declaring a new bean like the following and handle my custom implementation in it based on "CertificateProvidedSslBuilder"

```
@Requires(property = SslConfiguration.PREFIX + ".enabled", value = TRUE, defaultValue = FALSE)
@Requires(property = SslConfiguration.PREFIX + ".build-self-signed", value = FALSE, defaultValue = FALSE)
@Singleton
@Replaces(SslBuilder.class)
public class PublisherSslBuilder extends SslBuilder<SslContext> implements ServerSslBuilder {
```